# Hierarchical clustering R as filter variable

Tags: r, filter, cluster-analysis, feature-selection, hierarchical-clustering

I would like to test the added value of features compared to currently used predictors.

First, I checked if features were not correlated to the predictors (volume and intensity) I already use, and for the ones that are not correlated I would like to only keep the ones that are not highly correlated. So for each hierarchical cluster, I would like to keep the feature that is least correlated with volume and intensity, so far I only found how to delete all high correlations within the correlation matrix, but I would like to keep one per cluster. Is there any package or code in R that can do so?

So far I have this:

```
tmp <- cor(data)
tmp[upper.tri(tmp)] <- 0
diag(tmp) <- 0

data.new <- data[,!apply(tmp,2,function(x) any(x > 0.7))]
```

I'm quite new to coding, so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question. A better forum for this might be https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just out of curiosity @ScottH, why you did not suggest https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @AlvaroAGutierrezVargas, stats.stackexchange.com would also be a good venue. A lot of overlapping community between stats and datascience